# How to convert Win32 HRESULT to int return value?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm writing a Windows console application in C++ and would like to return zero on success and a meaningful error code on failure (i.e., `S_OK` should return 0, and `E_OUTOFMEMORY` should return a different return value than `E_FAIL` and so on). Is the following an okay approach?:

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr = DoSomething();
    return (int) hr;
}
```

Or is there a better way? Maybe a standard Win32 API function or macro that I'm forgetting or failing to find?

Comment: You accepted the answer that said to leave the cast in, which you don't need.

Comment: It's a matter of style, I guess, but just because you don't need the cast, doesn't mean it shouldn't be there to make it explicit that you definitely mean to convert the HRESULT to an int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HRESULT` is just a 32-bit integer, with each code being a different value, so [what you are doing is what you want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378137%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: If what he wants is for success to sometimes be represented by a non-zero value (S_FALSE?).  But he did say he wants to return zero on success.

Answer (score 8):

The OP wants a return value of zero to indicate success.  There are success codes which are non-zero and so...

```
if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
    return 0;
return hr;
```

Comment: +1 it is not enough assuming S_OK == 0, SUCCEEDED( ) should be used.

Comment: Good catch. Voted up. Still, in this case, I think I want to return a different value for S_FALSE and the like.

Answer (score 3):

There is an implicit conversion, so the cast is unnecessary.

(Rather more unfortunately, there is also an implicit conversion to `bool`, and to the Win32 `BOOL` typedef, so `S_OK` converts to false and all other values (including errors) convert to true - a common source of errors in COM programs.)

Answer (score 2):

The "better way" is to use a C++ style cast:

```
HRESULT hr = DoSomething();
return static_cast<int>(hr);
```

Otherwise, [like Steve said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218355/how-to-convert-win32-hresult-to-int-return-value/1218361#1218361), it's just an integer. It is defined as a `long`, not an `int`, but instead of casting from `HRESULT` to `long` to `int`, you can obviously just do it in one maneuver.

(That is to say, `windows.h` makes the assumption that `long` will be a 32-bit integer, which the C & C++ standard's do not guarantee. But that's just how things go, I suppose.)

---

Even better is that this does not require a cast at all.

Comment: As a matter of fact, since HRESULT is just a typedef for 'long' you don't even need a cast at all.

Comment: Hm, funny what happens when you stop looking at the big picture.