# How to fix "Run-Time Check Failure #0" error when trying to download a file with urlmon.dll?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, runtime-error, urlmon

I have written a downloader program in C++ using **urlmon.dll**.

I have used Visual Studio 2015 RTM as the IDE.

Here are my codes:

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include "clocale"
#include "fstream"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
using namespace std;

typedef int*(*tdDosyaIndir)(void*, char*, char*, DWORD, void*);

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "turkish");

string strAdres;

cout << "İndirilecek adresi girin:\n";
cin >> strAdres;

HINSTANCE dll = LoadLibrary(L"urlmon.dll");
tdDosyaIndir DosyaIndir = (tdDosyaIndir)GetProcAddress(dll, "URLDownloadToFileA");

DosyaIndir(0, &strAdres[0u], "dosya.html", 0, 0);

FreeLibrary(dll);

return 0;
}
```

But the problem is when I try to download something program shows this error:

[image: screenshot of dialog box]

What should I do in order to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the calling convention in the function pointer typedef.

Windows API functions generally use the `__stdcall` calling convention. However, C and C++ functions typically use the `__cdecl` calling convention, and that is the compiler's default. When there is a mismatch of the calling convention, the compiler generates the wrong code, and you get this error message.

To ensure the compiler generates the correct code to call the function, your typedef for it should look like this:

```
typedef HRESULT (__stdcall *tdDosyaIndir)(void*, char*, char*, DWORD, void*);
```

Comment: Ok, it worked; but it used to work without **__stdcall** in Code::Blocks. How do you explain this? Is it a Code::Blocks bug?

Comment: Why the `int *` return type? Doesn't `URLDownloadToFile` return a `long`?

Comment: I don't know Code::Blocks but maybe it uses the __stdcall calling convention by default? This is compiler specific behaviour in any case.

Comment: @melpomene Read this: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/1218361/10825637** HRESULT is 32-bit integer.

Comment: This is the correct declaration for URLDownloadToFile `HRESULT URLDownloadToFile(LPUNKNOWN, LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, DWORD, LPBINDSTATUSCALLBACK);` There's no reason not to use this in your typedef. `HRESULT` and `int*` are both 32 bits now, but there's no guarantee that they will be in the future.

Comment: @ÇAĞATAYKAYA Yes, so in other words, it is **not a pointer**. Why are you declaring it as returning a pointer?

Comment: @john I'm reasonably sure `int *` is not 32 bits on current 64-bit systems.

Comment: @ÇAĞATAYKAYA Well I'm making assumptions, my main point is like yours, the OP should use the correct declaration instead of making up stuff that may or may not be correct now or in the future.

Comment: @john Actually, I am not a programmer in spite of the fact that I can write complex programs. I am just a medical student and programming is my hobby. Maybe it will be my second job besides being a doctor. And yes, there is no reason like you said; but I don't understand Microsoft's Hungarian notation. I am not able to memorize them. I mean, I think there is no reason to write **LPCTSTR** instead of _const char*_.

Comment: Don't memorize them. *Understand* them. `LP` = long pointer, `C` = constant, `T` = generic text type (same as `_T` macro), `STR` = string. Lots of these things are legacy, of course. There is no longer a distinction between long (far) and short (near) pointers, so everything is now just `LP`. And `T` doesn't really matter anymore, because everything is Unicode (`W`). You don't need to worry about ANSI (`A`). If you want to learn Windows programming, do yourself a favor and pick up a used copy of Charles Petzold's *Programming Windows*, 5th edition (not a newer edition). @ÇAĞATAYKAYA

Comment: @CodyGray Ok, I found it. But why should I use old version of this book instead of new book?

Comment: The new books are about a different programming language. If you want to learn the Windows API, you need the 5th edition. It is the last one to talk about it. @ÇAĞATAYKAYA

Comment: @CodyGray The 6th edition teachs XAML, it is a C# thing; it is different like you said. By the way I am not interested with JITted languages and interpreted languages since I can write Delphi code when I want to make GUI app anyway.

Comment: `LPCTSTR` is a good example as it is **not** the same as `const char*`. It actually the same as `const TCHAR*` and what `TCHAR` is *depends on the compiler settings you are using*, it could be `char` but it might not be. And finally, my other point, the meaning of the Microsoft typedefs has changed in the past and could change in the future. So really it's best to use the correct definitions.